# Is there a way to remotely update a cell's contents without using scripts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

This is probably really basic but for the life of me I can't phrase this question in a way where google will point me in the direction of an answer.

**What I want is to take a cell that has had data manually inputted, and then be able to update that number in its original cell.** For example, someone fills in '11' and I can then add 2 to that number.

The only way I can think of to accomplish this is either with scripts or a sort of intermediary cell, but I'm unsure if there's some elegant way to directly edit a cell's contents from a different cell that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. No such elegant way.
You're not finding it because it's not possible.  You'd need to script something like that.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't finding anyone even asking the same question to find the 'no' I needed haha. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You're likely in the early stages of an xy problem :)
https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I'm creating a crafting calculator for a game. The user will input what items they need to craft and the calculator will tell them what materials they need in order to craft them. This part works fine. But I wanted to add functionality to simulate crafting an item so that you don't need to update all the numbers every time you craft something. So ideally when you craft something it'd update the numbers you entered, but I'll likely just need to use an intermediary column.